# how to ensure the value of an attribute in the set of values of another attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

This is a parameters configure.

```
<params>
  <param name="use-schema" />
  <param name="schema-domain" relyon="use-schema" />
  <param name="schema-file" relyon="use-schema" />
</params>
```

And this is part of XSD content.

```
<xs:element name="param">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="relyon" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I wrote some basic xsd, but there's no restriction for `relyon`, how to write an XSD to ensure the value of attribute `relyon` is announced in `params/param/@name`?

According to Michael's direction, I finished the task.

This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<params
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="params.xsd">
  <param name="use-schema" />
  <param name="schema-domain" relyon="use-schema" />
  <param name="schema-file" relyon="use-schema" />
</params>
```

This is the XSD file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="params">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="param" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="relyon" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="paramName">
            <xs:selector xpath="./param" />
            <xs:field xpath="@name" />
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="relyon" refer="paramName">
            <xs:selector xpath="./param" />
            <xs:field xpath="@relyon" />
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xs:key and xs:keyref. In your element declaration for params, declare a key with selector xpath="param", field xpath="@name", and a corresponding keyref with selector xpath="param", field xpath="@relyon".

Comment: key should be unique, and attribute `relyon` can share the same value, could they work together?

Comment: If I understand the question, yes.

Comment: I finished the task according to your direction. Thank you very much.